# Rudin's PMA: Trigonometric function

Tags: real-analysis

Cited from Rudin:

> Let us define $(46)$ $$C(x) = 2 [E(ix) + E( - ix)]$$
>
> $$S(x) = \frac{1}{2i} [E(ix) - E(-ix)]$$ We shall show that $C(x)$ and
> $S(x)$ coincide with the functions $cos(x)$ and $sin(x)$, whose
> definition is usually based on geometric considerations. By $(25)$
> $$E(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$$ $\overline{E(z)} =
> > E(\overline{z})$. Hence $(46)$ shows that $C(x)$ and $S(x)$ are real
> for real $x$. Also,$(47)$ $$E(ix) = C(x) + iS(x)$$ Thus $C(x)$ and
> $S(x)$ are the real and imaginary parts, respectively, of $E(ix)$, if
> $x$ is real. By $(27)$ $$E(z)E( - z) = E(z - z) = E(0) = 1$$, $(48)$
> $$|E(ix)|= E(ix)\overline{E(ix)} = E(ix)E( -ix) = 1$$ so that
> $$|E(ix)| = 1$$  ($x$ real).From $(46)$ we can read off that $C(0) =
> > 1$, $S(0) = 0$, and $(28)$ shows that$(49)$ $$C'(x) = -S(x)$$ $$ S'(x)
> > = C(x)$$ We assert that there exist positive numbers $x$ such that $C(x) = 0$. For suppose this is not so. Since $C(0) = 1$, it then
> follows that $C(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$, hence $S'(x) > 0$

After $(49)$, rudin said "Since $C(0)=1$, it then follows that $C(x)>0$ for all $x>0$", I don't understand how rudin derived it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Intermediate value theorem ? (+ please do not use links)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  In that paragraph, we assumed (with an eye toward contradiction) that there is no $x>0$ for which $C(x)=0$

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I think it's nothing about the theorem. It's strange that my photos don't show up.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I know that assumption, but it's also possible that $C(x)<0$ right? I don't get rudin's meaning that how to prevent this case.

Comment: No, since $C(0)=1>0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yeah I think this condition carefully but I still cannot get why it can imply $C(x)$ cannot be less than $0$, that's why I will ask this question, please forgive my dumbness.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Sorry for my arrogance, I know what you mean now, thank you for your help!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I get your meaning, thank you for your help!

Comment: $C$ is a continuous function, so if it is positive at one point and never equals $0$, then it must be positive everywhere. (Reason by contradiction with the Intermediate Value Theorem.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I have the same idea with you, thank you for your comment!

Comment: Perhaps you should post a short and correct answer to your question. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin OK, I've added it. :)

Comment: No, I meant to post it as an actual answer. If you accept the answer, the question will no longer appear on the unanswered list.

Comment: @TedShifrin OK, I've post it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, now I post the answer.

Because $E$ is a continuous function, $C$ is a continuous function. We also know that $C(0)=1>0$. If there exists $C(x) < 0$ for some $x > 0$, by the intermediate value theorem, there exists a $x>0$, $C(x)=0$ contradicts to the assumption.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).